# shell to send send output as attachment to email

Tags: linux, shell

I dont know what is wrong with this script. I am not getting any error and I am not getting this email as well.

Code:

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Filename:   mailx.ksh
    # Purpose:    Demonstrates how one can attach files when sending E-Mail
    #             messages from the Unix mailx utility.
    # Author:     Frank Naude, Oracle FAQ
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    SUBJECT="Send mail from Unix with file attachments"
    TO=abcd@gmail.com
    SPOOLFILE=/home/abcd/test_mail/sqlplus_test.txt
```

-- sql part ---

```
    echo "Produce listing from SQL*Plus..."
    sqlplus -s abcd/xxxxx >$SPOOLFILE <<-EOF
            set echo off feed off veri off pages 0 head off
            select count(*) from abcd;
            exit;
            EOF
```

-- send email with attachment

```
    echo -e "This email has a attachments" | mutt -a "${SPOOLFILE}" -s "This is a test email with attachment" -- abcd@gmail.com <<-EOF

            Hi,

            This sample E-mail message demonstrates how one can attach
            files when sending messages with the Unix mailx utility.


            Best regards

            ~.
            EOF
```

Comment: and you've tested your script from the command-line? your `echo -e "... | mutt .... <<EOF` is sending data via std-in through both a `|` (pipe) and a `HERE-DOC`, which I don't think is legal. I recommend putting the message "This email has attachments" inside the body of the `HERE-DOC`. Good luck.

Comment: Yes I ran this through cmd line as shell script.  I even tried removing the entire part beginning with Hi i.e., message body.

Comment: does `echo "this is a test" |  mutt -S "Subject : Test"  abcd@gmail.com` do anything? Are you sure there is a mail server running and that you can connect to it? I have used the `-a` option like `sendmail -a file -S sub << EOF msg EOF` (with EOF done as  you have on separate lines). Good luck.